# Python code is not executing in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, recursion, include, robotframework

Robot Framework File

```
Run Process | python | C:/file/set_rec.py
Open Browser | website.com/
Run some Kewords...
```

Python file

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

At first my ride code was just:

```
Open Browser | website.com/
Run some Keywords...
```

but after the test throw me the error massage:
**Python maximum recursion depth exceeded**
I found a solution at stackoverflow how to include .py in Robotframwork but I get the same error massage.

Comment: Your code is running. It looks like it has a bug which causes it to do infinite recursion. The problem isn't with robot, it's with your set_rec.py file.

Answer (score 1):

`Run Process` will execute an external process & then close it - that `setrecursionlimit()` will change it for that python.exe (only), and not affect the process your robot framework runs in.

I'd suggest looking into what's hitting the recursion limit in the first place & fixing it, that's probably a symptom of some more serious issue.
And if you do want to increase it for the python process the framework is running in, you could try with Evaluate (disclaimer - I personally don't know will this work):

```
Evaluate    sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```